# Replace values of a data frame based on specific criteria in R

Tags: r, replace, dataframe

I have a data frame and I would like to replace the first three values of a column for other 3 values. I have a list with the values I would like to replace.

Let's assume the following list:

```
Orig  Replacefor
AAA   111
BBB   222
CCC   333
DDD   444
EEE   555
```

I have the following data frame:

```
id       amount
AAAXXX   5
BBBXXX   13
CCCXXX   21
DDDXXX   22
EEEXXX   8
```

I would like the following output:

```
id      amount
111XXX  5
222XXX  13
333XXX  21
444XXX  22
555XXX  8
```

In my real example the x's could be any value and I would like to leave them unchanged.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your list is an a dataframe named `X` and the dataframe to be replaced is `DF`, use this:

```
DF <- within(DF, id2 <- paste0(X$Replacefor[match(substr(id,1,3), X$Orig)], substr(id, 4, nchar(as.character(id)))))
```

EDIT: tested and working. Note that `as.character` is needed if your `id` column is a factor.

This will create another column, `id2` in your dataframe. If you want to overwrite rhe original column, just remove the `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using `gsub` to replace a certain pattern in a vector by another pattern. If there are any questions, please feel free to ask!

```
# Sample data
df1 <- data.frame(Orig = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"), 
           Replacefor = c(111, 222, 333, 444, 555))

df2 <- data.frame(id = c("AAAXXX", "BBBXXX", "CCCXXX", "DDDXXX", "EEEXXX"), 
           amount = c(5, 13, 21, 22, 8))

# Pattern replacement
df2[, 1] <- sapply(1:nrow(df1), function(i) {
  # Row in df2 that matches pattern from column 1 of df1, e.g. "AAA"
  tmp.row <- grep(df1[i, 1], substr(df2[, 1], 1, 3))
  # Replace pattern with content from column 2 of df1, e.g. "111"
  paste(gsub(df1[i, 1], df1[i, 2], substr(df2[tmp.row, 1], 1, 3)), substr(df2[tmp.row, 1], 4, 6), sep = "")
})

df2 
      id amount
1 111XXX      5
2 222XXX     13
3 333XXX     21
4 444XXX     22
5 555XXX      8
```

Comment: What happens if the string `"XXX"` contains one of the patterns to be replaced?

Comment: You're right, thanks. Just updated my code with some `substr` commands.

Comment: I tried df2[, 1] <- sapply(1:nrow(df1), function(i) {tmp.row <- grep(df1[i, 1], substr(df2[, 1], 1, 3)) paste(gsub(df1[i, 1], df1[i, 2], substr(df2[tmp.row, 1], 1, 3)), substr(df2[tmp.row, 1], 4, 6), sep = "")})


I get an error: unexpected symbol .. What should be entered to join the 2nd and the third line? betwen ,3,)) and paste 

thanks